# Is it "the X day" or "on the X day"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Example sentence:

> The diet I picked was hard. Fortunately, I became used to it (on) the
>   second day.

Do I need the **on**? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a preposition of you want. I think *by* works as well as *on* in this context:

> The diet I picked was hard. Fortunately, I was used to it by the second day.

I also think the sentence is grammatical without the preposition, but it still reads a little choppy to me:

> The diet I picked was hard. Fortunately, I was used to it the second day.

I'd include a preposition, but that seems more of a stylistic issue than a grammatical one.